# How to use resource file for displaying column name in JQ grid

Tags: jqgrid

As by default the "colNames" property of the JQgrid displays the names that we harcode there like:

colNames: ['ProductID'],
                //columns model
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'ProductID', index: 'ProductID', align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                           ],

As here the "ProductID" in colnames property is harcoded here. Now my requirement is that this value should not be hard coded instead it should get the value from .resx file where we are maintaning the Translations.

Can we acheive this in jqgrid??

Comment: Chould you describe more detailed which technology you use on the server (ASP.NET MVC, WCF, ASMX, PHP, Java servlets...) ? Are all clients in the same language? Do you want to use language of the web browser or the language defined on the server?

Answer (score 0):

After reading of your question and thinking about all problems I made some minor changes in the localization files, made [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization.htm) and [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) demos and posted [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/) in the trirand forum. In [the second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) I use less known column templates which was implemented in jqGrid based on [one](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/templates-for-columns-in-colmodel/#p20807) from my previous feature requests. The usage of templates can reduce and the length of JavaScript code used jqGrid and simplify it.

In your case you can probably simplify my demos and load all column headers (or lables of `colModel`) and the grid title (the caption) from the resource file. You can choose the language based on headers of the HTTP requests (`Accept-Language`) received from the client.

The exact implementation on the server side will be very depend on the technology which you use on the server.